# Gmail, smtplib, Python. Fetch the oldest, least recent email

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

The following fetches the message body of the most recent email. Instead I need to retrieve the oldest/least recent. I assume I need to replace count[0] with something else to do this.

Please note I'm very new to all this

```
stat,count = mail.select('Inbox')
typ ,data = mail.search(None,'UnSeen')
stat,data = mail.fetch(count[0],'(BODY[TEXT])')

msgbody = data[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the 'count' list is message numbers sorted by date and `count[0]`
is the most recent `count[-1]` should fetch the least recent